# RewriteCond not finishing at rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !(abcdefg) index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

I expect this to load the file or directory if it exists, otherwise follow the last rule.

However, if the file or directory exists, it doesn't work and loads it under `?url=filename.png` anyway (when it should just load `/filename.png`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule` not all rules. And you must use `!-f` and `!-d` to avoid matching files & directories.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !(abcdefg) index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Or better one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule !(abcdefg) index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the rule doesn't quite work still. If I load /anypage it returns a 404. (expected index.php?url=anypage)

Comment: The better one works! I guess because it's better. Thanks.